# Unity3D top down plane banking calculation

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, dot-product, cross-product

currently I'm working on a top-down plane game, all movement is 2D using the X and Z axis. I've worked out the rotation based on the joystick direction, however, I want the plane to rotate on its Y-axis when turning and I can't find the best way to do this.

```
    if(movementInput)
    {
        localRawInput = rawLSInput;
        InputDirectionCache = rawLSInput;
    }
    else
    {
        localRawInput = InputDirectionCache;
    }

    targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(localRawInput, Vector3.up);
    currentRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(currentRotation, targetRotation, currentRotationSpeed);


    Vector3 targetRot = targetRotation.eulerAngles;
    Vector3 currentRot = currentRotation.eulerAngles;

    Vector3 currentDir = currentRotation * transform.forward;
    Vector3 targetDir = targetRotation * transform.forward;
```

This is how I calculate the rotation desired. The velocity just applies to forward of the plane when the rotation is applied (currentRotation is used to set the rotation)
I was using the targetDir and currentDir to calculate dot products and cross products to try get a value used to bank with no luck.

Sorry if it's a bit vague, i'm not too sure of the terminology of what i'm looking for

Comment: What is localRawInput? Is it a float for the input?

Comment: localRawInput is the direction from the Left Stick, I cache it so when theres no input, it keeps the same direction it was going rather than reverting to 0

Comment: Ok, thanks. Working on an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing all this stuff with the rotations, I would recommend using

```
float xRot = localRawInput.z * turnAmount
float zRot = localRawInput.x * turnAmount;

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRot, 0, zRot);
```

This makes it so when the stick tilts forward, the plane rotates on it's Z axis, making it tilt forward.

If you want the plane to slowly stop so it's smoother, you can use

```
// turnSpeed must be between 0 and 1
float xRot = Mathf.Lerp(transform.eulerAngles.x, localRawInput.z * turnAmount, turnSpeed);
float zRot = Mathf.Lerp(transform.eulerAngles.z, localRawInput.x * turnAmount, turnSpeed);

transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRot, 0, zRot);
```

This will turn the plane from the current rotation to the target rotation but only part of the way so as the distance gets smaller, it slows down.

Comment: Thanks, how would I go about the banking issue though?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean saving the input?

Comment: No, I mean when a plane turns, the plane rotates so the wing goes down or up

Comment: You could try also setting transform.up = Vector3.up

Comment: No, thats the desired effect... http://krepelka.com/fsweb/lessons/student/images/lesson2figure01.gif